# Palantir Pipeline Builder Date Transformation

Tags: apache-spark-sql, palantir-foundry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoA4H.png) This is one of the datasets.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsLqv.png) for the other data sets.

How can I match { 'November_Industry_Gross' & 'FY_2022_November_Industry_Gross'}  these formats with Date format so that the date from both the tables matches by using Pipeline Builder? Appreciate your help in my learning process.

Answer (score 0):

You can load both datasets in Pipeline Builder and create columns that will let you do the join.

For instance, you can:

- extract 3 columns from the second dataset (year, month, day)
- split date column of the first dataset as 3 columns as well (year, month, day)
- join on those 3 columns (year should match, month should match, day should match)

Specific transforms to obtain this can be `regex extract` and `extract date part`, and then a join.